# Kotlin dagger hilt injection is not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

i am trying to use dagger hilt, i set up everything, but i am getting and error when i try to use the object for witch i am created a dependency injection : `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property exoPlayer has not been initialized`

Here is my module provider :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ServiceComponent::class)
object ServiceModule {
    @ServiceScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideExoPlayer(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        audioAttributes: AudioAttributes
    ) = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
        setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
        setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
    }
}
```

In my activity i got :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AudioActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Player.EventListener { {

    @Inject
    lateinit var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer
```

then i try to add a listener in the onCreate

```
exoPlayer.addListener(this)
```

But here i got the error that it's not initialized, i don't realy understand because i though that the all point of dependency injection was to provide an construct that can be injected everywhere. So why it has not been initialized?

Comment: Is your application class annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`?

Comment: Can you add your `onCreate` function in the question?

Comment: My application is hiltandroidapp and my on create only add the listener of now

Comment: But i tried that my activity is the event listener of my Exoplay so it's might come for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually providing your `SimpleExoPlayer` object in `ServiceComponent`. As you're expecting to inject the `SimpleExoPlayer` in Activity, you should provide it in `ActivityComponent` instead. I think you may need a module or reuse existing one

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class ActivityModule {
    
    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideExoPlayer(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        audioAttributes: AudioAttributes
    ) = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
        setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
        setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to change the ServiceComponent into ApplicationComponent, but it's doesn't work i still got the error : lateinit property exoPlayer has not been initialized

Comment: just noticed you were using object, how about using class instead for the module

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that in your `AudioActivity` in `onCreate()` you are only adding a listener. So given that you set up all the plugins and dependencies correctly in your app/module, you probably have forgotten to call `super.onCreate()` in your activity (where the injection magic happens), which is needed before you start touching any of the injected fields.